# Создание класса с указателем на другой класс

Tags: c++

Учу C++. Пишу свой велосипед (сугубо для учёбы) в виде рендера для командной строки Windows. Возникла дилемма, которую не знаю, как решить

**Дано:**

1. Абстрактный класс **«RenderDataObject»** для наследования другими классами. У класса есть виртуальная функция **«GetData()»**, которая обязана перегружаться потомками
2. Класс **«Render»**. Он имеет вектор, который хранит указатели на объекты класса **«RenderDataObject»**. При вызове другой функции класс **«Render»** обходит вектор и вызывает у объектов **«RenderDataObject»** функцию **«GetData()»**, после чего происходит отрисовка

Для связи между двумя этими класса в конструктор класса **«RenderDataObject»** я передаю указатель на класс **«Render»** и храню его.
В конструкторе мы вызываем функцию **«Render::AddObject(RenderDataObject* A)»**, чтобы добавить указатель в вектор.
В деструкторе вызываем функцию **«Render::RemoveObject(RenderDataObject* A)»**, чтобы удалить указатель из вектора

**Проблема:**
Как корректно сделать связь между ними?
Передача указателя класса **«Render»** в конструктор **«RenderDataObject»** вроде бы и неплохая идея, но для любого потомка нужно будет передавать указатель, что как-то странно выглядит. Плюс может быть куча других параметров и, как мне кажется, это очень неудобно

Думал над тем, чтобы класс **«Render»** имел шаблонную функцию, которая бы создавала объект и возвращала его, но тогда никак нельзя передать параметры в конструктор класса-потомка. Плюс такое даже скомпилировать не получилось, хотя может я делал что-то не так

Ещё возник вариант с глобальной переменной класса **«Render»** в файле .h/.cpp и абстрактный класс может ей пользоваться, но как-то это тоже очень странно выглядит

UPD:
Оказывается я неправильно писал шаблонную функцию, сейчас получилось.
Но возникла другая проблема: как можно передать параметры в конструктор потомка? Ведь, теоретически, эту функцию может использовать любой потомок класса «RenderDataObject»

```
class RenderDataObject
{
    const char* abstractData = "Data abstract class";

public:
    RenderDataObject()
    {

    }
    virtual const char* GetData() = 0;
};

class myObject : public RenderDataObject
{
private:
    const char* objectData = "Data my object";

public:
    myObject(const char* data)
    {
        objectData = data;
    }
    const char* GetData()
    {
        return "Hello, world!";
    }
};

std::vector<RenderDataObject*> vector;

template <class T>
T* Create()
{
    T* value = new T;
    vector.push_back(value);
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    myObject* obj = Create<myObject>();
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Может написать все так, чтобы `RenderDataObject`-у не нужен был указатель на `Render`? *"чтобы класс «Render» имел шаблонную функцию, которая бы создавала объект и возвращала его, но тогда никак нельзя передать параметры в конструктор ... даже скомпилировать не получилось"* Почему нельзя? Покажите код. *"возник вариант с глобальной переменной ... очень странно выглядит"* Действительно выглядит не очень.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, обновил вопрос. Ещё попытался погуглить - не получается. Видимо гуглю неправильно или такое просто невозможно

Comment: Про шаблонную функцию: `template <typename T, typename ...P> T *Create(P &&... params) {T *value = new T(std::forward<P>(params)...);`.